# Alias to static class System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager;

Tags: c#, static-members

I would like to declare an alias to the static class : `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager;`

I would like this alias to be available to all the methods of my class so I've tried to do that :

```
public class MyClass 
{
   using conf = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager;

   public void MethodOne()
   {
      string appConfigStr = conf.AppSettings["someAppSettings"].ToString()
   }
}
```

**But the above raises the following error** : Invalid token 'using' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Is there something I can do to alias this configuration manager class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`using` directives can be used to create an alias within the scope of the current `.cs` file.

```
using conf = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass 
    {
        public void MethodOne()
        {
            string appConfigStr = conf.AppSettings["someAppSettings"].ToString()
        }
    }
}
```

See [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) for more information

Comment: I give you the answer because you were the first to explain that I could use the using inside the file and outside the Namespace Thanks !

Comment: Either way works, actually. The docs give examples of `using` directives both inside and outside the `namespace` scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a `using` statement inside a class. The error message you are getting is very specific in this regards.
To solve it, simply put it outside of your class:

```
using conf = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager;

public class MyClass 
{
    public void MethodOne()
    {
        string appConfigStr = conf.AppSettings["someAppSettings"].ToString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`using` to create aliases must be used outside a class scope, but in in the assembly or namespace scope!

```
// Here here here here here here :)
using conf = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager;

public class MyClass 
{
   public void MethodOne()
   {
      string appConfigStr = conf.AppSettings["someAppSettings"].ToString()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must place that using statement outside of your class definition just like the compiler is telling you.

```
using conf = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager;

public class MyClass 
{
   public void MethodOne()
   {
      string appConfigStr = conf.AppSettings["someAppSettings"].ToString()
   }
}
```

Please refer to the C# language specification under section 9.4 "Using directives".